# Showing next row in database

Tags: php, mysql, row, blogs

I was looking for a way to create very simple blog. When I was looking through stack overflow. I came a across a way, that could work for me. However there is this error in it. I could not find the question where I got this code from.  Anyway first I got an error that I have fixed, but know I  cannot get any echo out.  My table has some content but no echo`s out.

So I got my database:  id, title,  date,  posted by,  article.
That I got the PHP code:

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("prive", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog LIMIT {$_POST['count']},1");
if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='result'>".$row['titel'] . " " . $row['datum']."</div>";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And know my html

```
    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="content">
<div id="results">
   <div class="result"></div>
   <div class="result"></div>
   <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="showMore" />Show more</a>

    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $number = $('.result').size();

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "getNext.php",
           data: {"count":$number},
           success: function(results){
             $('#results').append(results);
           }
         });

      });

});
</script>
```

Comment: try changing `$number` to `number` in jquery part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check userinput everytime.
I suggest that you do something like this in your php-file:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog";
if(isset($_POST['count']))
{
    $query .= " LIMIT " . intval($_POST['count'] . ",1");
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This should work. But the next problem is in your javascript. You have an error in your code. In javascript you define a variable with var not with $ (this is php).
So use:

```
var number = $('.result').size();
...
data: {"count": number},
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['count'])
{ 

Gives a error with {, I tried checkking the code and chaning a few things my self, but I could not fix this error

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot a bracket!
if(isset($_POST['count']))